# Backpropagation, Cross-entropy Loss and the Softmax Function

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network, backpropagation

I was reading this article: https://stackabuse.com/creating-a-neural-network-from-scratch-in-python-multi-class-classification/.
If you read the whole code at the end of the article, you will notice that the author does NOT start backprop from the loss function (cross-entropy) as it should be. Rather, it starts the backward process from the softmax output.

My questions:

1. Why doesn't he optimize the cross-entropy loss, preferring the optimization of the softmax output?

Tentative answer: if the labels are one-hot encoded, then we just end up with one term in the cross-entropy summation expression, that is the negative logarithm of the softmax output for the correct class. So, optimizing the softmax is equivalent to optimizing the cross-entropy. 
Am I right?

2. Given that one wants to optimize the softmax, look at how he calculates the (intermediate) derivative of the softmax with respect to the logits from the last fully connected: `dcost_dzo = ao - one_hot_labels`. This just subtracts '1' from the softmax output for the correct class.. He doesn't even use the analytical derivative of the softmax.. Why can one do that?
3. Suppose that my answer to question 1 stands true.. But if we wanted, for the sake of clarity, to start the backward process with the cross-entropy loss, explicitly using the expressions for the derivatives of both the loss function and the softmax function. How would we code this?

Thanks.

Comment: You sound confused; the softmax output should indeed be included in the cross-entropy loss calculation. Not sure your 3rd question makes any sense, and in any case "*how we would code this?*" sounds too broad a question for here - you are very welcome to try it and come back if you face *specific* issues.

Comment: @desertnaut Thanks for your reply. To attempt coding point 3 as you suggest, I have to understand points 1 and 2 first (the order of my questions was not random). Note that I am certainly confused, but I did NOT ask whether the SM should be included in the crossentropy calculation. I asked why the derivatives of the crossentropy function *and* of the softmax function don't seem to appear in the first step of backprop, that is `dcost_dzo = ao - one_hot_labels`.